# Make a column fluid down to min-width, then push float sidebar down

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

Suppose you have two divs: one with fluid width with a min-width and another div that's floating to the right.  For example, this [live demo (with code) at jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/esezer/2/edit) has this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="fixedFloatingColumn">fixed-size column<br />o<br />o<br />o<br />o</div>
  <div id="fluidNonfloatingColumnContainer">
    <div class="column">stretchable column 1</div>
    <div class="column">stretchable column 2</div>
    <div class="column">stretchable column 3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

if you resize the browser and make it narrower, the fluid div adjusts accordingly, until it hits the min-width.  After that, if you narrow the window even more, the horizontal scrollbar appears and the right floating div starts to overflow hidden to the right of the window.

What I'd like is, if the user keeps narrowing the window, after the non-floating div hits the min-width, the browser should push the floating sidebar div down below the non-floating content, instead of overflowing (hiding) to the right.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so, if you're willing to use media queries. For a short primer on how to do "responsive web design" I'd start by looking at this [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) by Ethan Marcotte. Simon Collison's website is an excellent [example](http://colly.com/) of what I think you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Pretty interesting.  Didn't know about media queries.  They sound like a recent development though; so I guess what I'm trying to do may not be doable with traditional CSS?

Comment: Media queries are CSS3, so they aren't natively supported in IE6-8, but you can use a javascript polyfill called respond.js: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/respondjs_fast_css3_media_queries_for_internet_explorer_6_8_and_more/ to use them for those versions of IE.